# MySQL Still Slow After Indexing

Tags: mysql

I have this table :

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_name | varchar(32)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| timestamp   | varchar(32)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| pair_name   | varchar(8)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bid_price   | decimal(20,8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ask_price   | decimal(20,8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and it has more than 700K rows. since it's slow when I try to SELECT something, I decided to add INDEX :

```
ALTER TABLE price_trading ADD INDEX price_trading_index (client_name, timestamp, pair_name);

+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| price_trading |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id          | A         |      715216 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |          |
| price_trading |          1 | price_trading_index |            1 | client_name | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |          |
| price_trading |          1 | price_trading_index |            2 | timestamp   | A         |       41897 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |          |
| price_trading |          1 | price_trading_index |            3 | pair_name   | A         |      740698 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |          |
+---------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

when I run this syntax :

```
SELECT * FROM price_trading WHERE timestamp = 'lm83-1524620255198';
```

the result is this :

```
18 rows in set (23.43 sec)
```

how to speed up query? why it seems that indexing method can't make it faster?

thank you.

Comment: Because the `timestamp` on the second place and you don't use condition by `client_name` in your query. Try to change order in your index to `(timestamp, client_name, pair_name)`. Or make another index only by `timestamp`.

Comment: Use specific column names over `*` in `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: @Leran2002 : you're right, bro. I put WHERE client_name and now it's fast. but I have a question...

if I have multiple queries, some of them only use timestamp, and some other use client_name AND timestamp, do I need to add 2 different indexing order?

Comment: @Saint Robson - Try to make one more index only by `timestamp`. I think it must help. Or test your queries with the following index `(timestamp, client_name, pair_name)` - if you use only the following conditions `timestamp and client_name` and `timestamp`.

Comment: Also your timestamp should be an int or bigint it will helps to optimize data and also for query.

Comment: @Saint Robson - The composite index `(timestamp, client_name, pair_name)` can use for conditions `where timestamp=... and client_name=...` and `where timestamp=...` but this index can't use for `where client_name=...`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using composite index and composite index works from left to right in your case it will work for
1) client_name and timestamp and pair_name
2) client_name and timestamp
3) client_name

So for your requirement create separate index for timestamp column.